# Exotic syntax in Javascript ": ?"

Tags: javascript

I was looking at a repo on Github when I stumbled on this file :
https://github.com/cdebotton/react-universal/blob/master/app/entryPoints/client.js
And more precisely the line 13:

```
let createDevToolsWindow: ?Function;
```

And I have no idea what this "[...]? :Function;" syntax is. I looked in the commits which introduced it, I searched in ES2015+, tried to find it on Google but I don't know how it's called so I didn't find anything.

Is this some Node thing? Or am I just really bad at JS?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is using [flow](https://flowtype.org/) and the prefixed `?` means that null is allowed. More [examples](https://flowtype.org/docs/syntax.html#array-types):

```
var array_of_num: number[] = [];
var array_of_num_alt: Array<number> = [];
var optional_array_of_num: ?number[] = null;
var array_of_optional_num: Array<?number> = [null, 0];
```

Another example:

```
// okay, 1 is a number
var good: number = 1;  

// okay, we have a ?
var good_nullable: ?number = null; 

// not okay, no ? means null is not a valid value for this variable.    
var bad: number = null;
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it's used to specify the type of the variable, like you would do in C, for example?

    "int num = 0;"

But with a '?' you specify the var can also be 'null'.

Comment: Right, I recommend spending a few minutes with the getting started tutorial: https://flowtype.org/docs/getting-started.html I'll add another example too.